# can we have more than one parameter inside showAsAction

Tags: android

I want to add two action in showAsAction like given below

```
app:showAsAction="always|never|ifRoom|withText|collapseActionView"
```

Is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed ,we can use one or two or more than that values inside `showAsAction` like give below

```
android:showAsAction="values"
```

or

```
app:showAsAction="values"
```

AND

Values will be

```
always|never|ifRoom|withText|collapseActionView
```

for more details logon to following link

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use more than one. For example `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` will only display the item in the action bar if there is room and will include title label.